# StatusBar goes in the background in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

[image]

I am trying to keep the status bar visible(example in Screen 1) for a view when the keyboard comes up(example in Screen 2) and the view is shifted up, but the status bar is overlapped by the view making it translucent.

I have set the following properties of the story board:
[image]

And have also specified the following code in the viewDidLoad():

```
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
```

to fix the status bar issue.
Kindly help me out to fix this thing, can't figure out this as I am new to iOS.